# Django Page not found

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to create urls to go to links like this: examples.com/baiviet/post-example/

- *post-example is a slug

this is my root urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

Then, this is my blog/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                       url(r'^baiviet/(?P<slug>)/$', views.view_post, name='viewpost'),
                       )
```

My views.py:

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    getpost = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'view_post.html', {'post':getpost})
```

And my view_post.html:

```
{{ post.content }}
```

The only thing I have is "Page Not Found" Error. I have tried to solve it and it takes me 2 hours before posting this question. I hope that someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for 404 is that in your root `urlconf`, you have

```
url(r'^$', include('blog.urls'))
```

Here, `$` indicates end of url pattern. Change that to

```
url(r'^/', include('blog.urls'))
#      ^ note the $ shoudl be replaced by / when you are doing an include.
```

Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs):

> Note that the regular expressions in this example don’t have a $ (end-of-string match character) but do include a trailing slash. Whenever Django encounters include() (django.conf.urls.include()), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

The issue with the missing pattern, as alecxe mentions on `<slug>` would arise *after* it resolves this issue (404).

EDIT:

For you to access the homepage, you need to have a trailing `/` or have the setting `APPEND_SLASH` setting to `True`. Since your URL Pattern is expecting a prefix of `/` - Now, if you dont want it, in your root urlconf, change `r'^/'` to just `r'^'`

Comment: @alecxe The complete answer is a combination of the 2 :)

Comment: thanks you, but now I can't enter homepage @karthikr

Answer (score 2):

You have an *empty capturing group* configured for the url:

```
url(r'^baiviet/(?P<slug>)/$', views.view_post, name='viewpost')
                  HERE ^
```

You need to provide a pattern for a slug to match, e.g. alphanumeric, underscore and a dash:

```
url(r'^baiviet/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', views.view_post, name='viewpost')
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but it does not work. I sill receive the 404 error

Comment: @user2622760 okay, let's debug it. Set `DEBUG=True` in settings and see what would be opened in the browser - you should get Django's debug page with more information. Also, check if `view_post` view is actually called.

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in ASIMC.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
The current URL, baiviet/ti-sao-nen-hc-tp-ti-canada/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: @user2622760 looks like it doesn't even try the urls from your app - karthikr's answer should solve it, check it out.